# Unable to set Signal as default SMS app

Tags: sms, default-applications, signal-private-messenger

I tried to set Signal as the default SMS app on my Samsung Galaxy S23+ after I enabled the SMS permission, but for some reason, it won't let me or even make it show up on the default apps menu as an option.

Other new apps are not showing either, although IDrive is showing up as an option that I got a while back even if it's not an actual SMS app. Starting to think there may be something weird I did to my phone that is causing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Signal got rid of SMS support in October 2022. They posted [this blog](https://signal.org/blog/sms-removal-android/) explaining their decision:

> We have now reached the point where SMS support no longer makes sense. For those of you interested, we walk through our reasoning in more detail below.

further adding

> In order to enable a more streamlined Signal experience, we are starting to phase out SMS support from the Android app. You will have several months to transition away from SMS in Signal, to export your SMS messages to another app, and to let the people you talk to know that they might want to switch to Signal, or find another channel if not.